# Unsung hero badge

Tags: discussion

The Unsung Hero badge is described as "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total".

Does that mean it is possible to lose the badge after it has been awarded, based upon future post answers etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Badges are never lost once awarded.